# How to use correctly the Query Window in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What should I do to avoid that commands be executed each time I hit 'Execute !. icon'

I mean this

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE Sales
GO
USE Sales;
GO
CREATE TABLE Customers(
CustomerID int NOT NULL,
LName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
FName varchar (50) NULL,
Status varchar (10),
ModifiedBy varchar (30) NULL        
    )
GO
```

When I click Execute!, Sql Server tries to redo the same thing.

What I do for now is to delete the **Query Window** completely then write what I need before clicking the Execute icon. But, I doubt that I should be doing that.

What can I do to keep writing the commands without having each time to clear the Query Window?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight the command you wish to run prior to hitting execute and it will only run the selected query text, alternatively you can comment a single line out with a double dash sign e.g. -- , or comment a block of text out with /*  */

Comment: I see. So, there is no other way of preventing the query window to execute again commands that are present. Thanks to all

Comment: You can select text you want commented out (usually whole lines) and press `Ctrl-K Ctrl-C` to comment that out. `Ctrl-K Ctrl-U` to uncomment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are only two option:

- ctr + a en then delete
- open a new query window

Answer (score 0):

**New Query Window**

Use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new window, write your query in there.

**SELECT what you want**

Click the Right Mouse button and drag to select what you want to execute, then execute the query